How to use Therad Groups in cycle in Jmeter?
I have few ThreadGroup element in Jmeter script. And i want to run it one after another in infinite cycle. How can i do it?
Add this for validation of stackoverflow
"information_for_calculation_period": {
             "is_alimony_received": false,
            "is_recipient_of_foreign_income": true,
            "is_under23_and_unscholarshipped_student": false,
            "is_recipient_of_educational_benefits": false,
            "is_served_military_service_by_conscription": false,
            "is_recipient_of_judges_retirement_benefit": false,
            "is_compensation_received_for_duties": false,
            "is_under_long_term_medical_treatment": true,
            "is_recipient_of_one_time_service_termination_benefit": false,
            "is_recipient_of_law_enforcement_pension": true, 
            "is_pregnant_family_member_during_income_period_or_application": false          


Or i need other way to  send  different grpc requests for 15 users in parallel way

As of JMeter 5.6.3 it is not possible to run Thread Groups in loop, there are following options:

Use your operating system scripting mechanisms to run a JMeter test plan in command-line non-GUI mode as many times as needed
Move the logic of your multiple Thread Groups into Test Fragments and reference them with Module Controllers where required


Can you explain about second way ? Can`t understand yet
